# Modifying CUDA and cpp Makefile

Tags: c++, cuda, makefile

I am trying to modify my makefile to support .cpp and .cu, however, I keep getting an error such as:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.text+0x20): error: undefined reference to 'main'
hostCode.o:displayfunc.cpp:function readScene(char*): error: undefined reference to 'camera'
hostCode.o:displayfunc.cpp:function readScene(char*): error: undefined reference to 'camera'
hostCode.o:displayfunc.cpp:function readScene(char*): error: undefined reference to 'camera'
hostCode.o:displayfunc.cpp:function readScene(char*): error: undefined reference to 'camera'
hostCode.o:displayfunc.cpp:function readScene(char*): error: undefined reference to 'sphereCount'
hostCode.o:displayfunc.cpp:function readScene(char*): error: undefined reference to 'sphereCount'
hostCode.o:displayfunc.cpp:function readScene(char*): error: undefined reference to 'sphereCount'
hostCode.o:displayfunc.cpp:function readScene(char*): error: undefined reference to 'spheres'
hostCode.o:displayfunc.cpp:function readScene(char*): error: undefined reference to 'spheres'
hostCode.o:displayfunc.cpp:function readScene(char*): error: undefined reference to 'sphereCount'
hostCode.o:displayfunc.cpp:function idleFunc(): error: undefined reference to 'updateRendering()'
hostCode.o:displayfunc.cpp:function reshapeFunc(int, int): error: undefined reference to 'reInitCamera(bool)'
hostCode.o:displayfunc.cpp:function keyFunc(unsigned char, int, int): error: undefined reference to 'reInitCamera(bool)'
```

**Makefile**

```
CXX = g++
NVCC = nvcc -ccbin $(CXX)


INCLUDES := -I/home/cuda_app/inc/

LDFLAGS = -lGL -lGLU -lglut -lpthread


ALL:= test

test:    hostCode.o deviceCode.o

        $(NVCC) $(INCLUDES) -o $@ $< $(LDFLAGS)

deviceCode.o: SmallPtCUDA.cu

        $(NVCC) $(INCLUDES) -o $@ -c $< $(LDFLAGS)


hostCode.o: displayfunc.cpp

        $(CXX) $(INCLUDES) -o $@ -c $< $(LDFLAGS)

clean:

        rm -rf  *.o  $(ALL)
```

How can I compile both `.cpp` and `.cu`?

Can anybody help with this please? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When asking a question about build errors, it's always best to include not just the errors but also the command invoking the compiler or linker.  With errors like this the problem is there; seeing the error messages is helpful but not definitive.

In your case the problem is your link command is incorrect in your makefile:

```
test:    hostCode.o deviceCode.o
        $(NVCC) $(INCLUDES) -o $@ $< $(LDFLAGS)
```

You are using `$<` here which expands to just the *first* prerequisite.  If you'd included the link line and examined it you'd see that the `deviceCode.o` file is not present on the link line.  You want your link command to look like this:

```
test:    hostCode.o deviceCode.o
        $(NVCC) $(INCLUDES) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)
```

Using `$^` which expands to *all* the prerequisites.

Also, just a note that by convention `LDFLAGS` contains linker options like `-L`, and `LDLIBS` is used for linker options like `-l`.  However your setup will work (it's just not conventional).